# How to mock Netty?

Tags: mocking, netty

I just inherited a project using netty and it seems to entangle itself in the code in that many handlers are created implementing netty interfaces, etc. I want to mock it in such a way that I can add tests to test from the netty api upwards, firing bytes in and receiving bytes back but not connecting a socket to do so. Is there any way to fire into the pipeline myself which would test netty code as well as our code and also receive from the code?

Specifically, I am looking to do something like this:

```
SysUnderTest(channel) {
  channel.addReadListener(myListenerImpl);
}

Test {
   testStuff() {
       channelMock = new MockChannel(); 
       SysUnderTest system = new SysUnderTest(channelMock);
       //BIG NOTE: The get here is just getting what the mocked cached when the SysUnderTest
       //ended up calling the channel.addReadLsitener(listenerImpl)!!!
       ReadListener listenerImplToTest = channelMock.getAddedListenerImpl();
       listenerImplToTest.fireNewDataIncoming(byteBuffer1);
       Assert.Equals("new state", system.getState());
       listenerImplToTest.fireNewDataIncoming(byteBuffer2);
       Assert.Equals("state2", system.getState());
   }
}
```

Maybe I need a paradigm shift but I think any system testing with an IO library should be firing data to a listener that will react. My test needs to fire data in by invoking the listener implementation's event method (and it gets the listenerImpl though the mock channel), but I don't see how to do this in netty. Specifically, which method is firing data in for the example above. It looks like it's reading the data (which seems more like a blocking/polling thing). Maybe I need to change my paradigm of the way I am thinking about this though?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, have a look at the embedder package in the [javadoc](http://netty.io/docs/stable/api/), Especially the DecoderEmbedder class.

Comment: hmmmm, it says "without setting up the pipeline"  I am trying to simulate a full blow QA test really here where I pass in a mock something but createpipeline is being done by the code....I can't change that really.  Will this still work somehow?

Comment: This now links to a 404 page.

Comment: In Netty 4, DecoderEmbedder was replaced with EmbeddedChannel.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using mock objects.

See https://github.com/netty/netty/pull/119.

```
 @Test
 public void testPerformOpeningHandshake() {
     Channel channelMock = EasyMock.createMock(Channel.class);

     DefaultChannelPipeline pipeline = createPipeline();

     EasyMock.expect(channelMock.getPipeline()).andReturn(pipeline);

     // capture the http response in order to verify the headers
     Capture<HttpResponse> res = new Capture<HttpResponse>();
     EasyMock.expect(channelMock.write(capture(res))).andReturn(new DefaultChannelFuture(channelMock, true));

     replay(channelMock);

     HttpRequest req = new DefaultHttpRequest(HTTP_1_1, HttpMethod.GET, "/chat");
     req.setHeader(Names.HOST, "server.example.com");
     req.setHeader(Names.UPGRADE, WEBSOCKET.toLowerCase());
     req.setHeader(Names.CONNECTION, "Upgrade");
     req.setHeader(Names.SEC_WEBSOCKET_KEY, "dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==");
     req.setHeader(Names.SEC_WEBSOCKET_ORIGIN, "http://example.com");
     req.setHeader(Names.SEC_WEBSOCKET_PROTOCOL, "chat, superchat");
     req.setHeader(Names.SEC_WEBSOCKET_VERSION, "13");

     WebSocketServerHandshaker17 handsaker17 = new WebSocketServerHandshaker17("ws://example.com/chat", "chat", false);
     handsaker17.performOpeningHandshake(channelMock, req);

     Assert.assertEquals("s3pPLMBiTxaQ9kYGzzhZRbK xOo=", res.getValue().getHeader(Names.SEC_WEBSOCKET_ACCEPT));
     Assert.assertEquals("chat", res.getValue().getHeader(Names.SEC_WEBSOCKET_PROTOCOL));
 }
```

Comment: What is your system under test in that example?  WebSocketServerHandshaker17?  and if so, AFTER I give the channelMock, I need to push data just like it is pushed from nio to the system undertest...it would not be read, right because in nio reads all are pushed as they come in.  Let me edit my post a bit as an example